# Bad argument `LOG' when configuring iptables

Tags: debian, iptables

I am trying to write a iptables sh script that later i can have updated from one spot for all my servers.  So far I have this that works.

i get this error

```
Bad argument `LOG'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

first i wipe to some defaults
iptables-restore /etc/iptables.conf

then load a file of ip ranges or just single ips

```
_input=/root/firewall/badips.db
_pub_if="eth0"
IPT=/sbin/iptables

$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

egrep -v "^#|^$" x | while IFS= read -r ip
do
        $IPT -A INPUT -i ${_pub_if} -s $ip -j LOG --log-prefix " Drop BadIP "
done <"${_input}"

$IPT -I INPUTlist
$IPT -I OUTPUTlist
$IPT -I FORWARDlist

$IPT -A INPUT -i ${_pub_if} -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -m limit --limit 30/sec  -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${_pub_if}  -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -m limit --limit 30/sec -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${_pub_if}  -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 5 -m limit --limit 30/sec -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${_pub_if}  -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -m limit --limit 30/sec -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Is this in a VM or the cloud or something?  **Are you sure you are running a stock Debian kernel**, or are you using something compiled for that environment?

Comment: Don't build firewalls this way. Use a proper firewall building tool like ufw.

Answer (score 2):

**If in doubt about bash behaviour: quote your untrusted inputs.**

If you have a line with just a space in your `badips.db` file, then that line equates to:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s -j LOG --log-prefix " Drop BadIP "
```

The error message doesnt pinpoint the problem because of the way iptables parses arguments initially ignoring the fact that `-j` is not a valid argument to `-s` and getting stuck on the next argument.

The current impact of malicious entries in your `badips.db` is "code execution with root privileges", so definitely ensure your script is handling invalid source ips/nets properly.